# Multiple VisualState Triggers for a single Visual State

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to write a `VisualState` for my new Universal app under Windows 10.
According to the documentation about [`VisualState.StateTriggers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.statetriggers.aspx), you can add multiple triggers to a visual state, as the property is of type `IList<StateTriggerBase>`.

The `VisualState` class documentation also points out to the `StateTriggers` documentation:

> *oneOrMoreTriggers*
>
> One or more triggers that can be an AdaptiveTrigger or a custom trigger derived from StateTriggerBase. These can be used to indicate when the corresponding VisualState needs to be applied automatically without an explicit GoToState call. See Remarks on the StateTriggers property for more info.

However, the documentation doesn't point out how multiple triggers work here.
Neither is there a way to modify the behavior by any C# code.
My desired behavior would require some `AND/OR` conditions for those trigger specified in the `StateTriggers` section.

Is there any other way, than writing my own `"MultiTrigger"`, deriving from `StateTriggerBase`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. As there is no built in `MultiTrigger`, I wrote my own `MultiTrigger`.
The multi trigger supports `AND` and `OR` conditions, which is exactly what I needed.

It is now included in the NuGet Package [**AdaptiveTriggerLibrary**](http://herdo.github.io/AdaptiveTriggerLibrary/).

Comment: I've installed the AdaptiveTriggerLibrary in my UWP project (built for RS1) and I'm trying to get two MultiTriggers with an AndModifier working with a WindowHeightTrigger and a WindowWidthTrigger each, but it seems that the first MultiTrigger is always active over the second one no matter what I do. Do you have a support email for that library, where can I get some help about it? Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio0694 Feel free to open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Herdo/AdaptiveTriggerLibrary - I'll look into it, as soon as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Herdo,
What I have observed in the `StateTriggers` behaviors is that when triggers are in the same group they are executed in a mutually exclusive way in order, sort of the `AND` mode.
`AND` triggers from different `VisualStateGroups` execute independently, sort of the `OR` mode.
In this observed behavior, I organize things that change the same set of properties into the same group, so that the condition is controlled inside the group.

Answer (score -2):

Try using distinct VisualStateGroups.
For example to handle different widths and orientations use 2 VisualStateGroups

```
<VisualStateGroups x:Name="WidthStates">
    ...
</VisualStateGroups> 

<VisualStateGroups x:Name="OrientationStates">
    ...
</VisualStateGroups>
```

view this related question on msdn:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/95291be1-25c7-4310-bb2b-b8fcead3b4d9/multiple-statetriggers-supporting-narrow-and-landscape